# How to superimpose bar plots in R?

Tags: r, plot, charts, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a figure similar to the one below (taken from Ro, Russell, & Lavie, 2001). In their graph, they are plotting bars for the errors (i.e., accuracy) within the reaction time bars.  Basically, what I am looking for is a way to plot bars within bars.

[image: stacked bar chart]

I know there are several challenges with creating a graph like this. First, Hadley points out that it is not possible to create a graph with two scales in ggplot2 because those graphs are fundamentally flawed (see [Plot with 2 y axes, one y axis on the left, and another y axis on the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right))

Nonetheless, the graph with superimposed bars seems to solve this dual sclaing problem, and I'm trying to figure out a way to create it in R. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please consider reading up how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Include what you've tried yourself. Note that double-yaxis are generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: for the superimposed bars you could use something like that ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(width=.5) + geom_bar(data=mtcars2, aes(x=factor(cyl)), width=.2, color="lightblue")

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly easy in base R, by using `par(new = T)` to add to an existing graph

```
set.seed(54321) # for reproducibility

data.1 <- sample(1000:2000, 10)
data.2 <- sample(seq(0, 5, 0.1), 10)

# Use xpd = F to avoid plotting the bars below the axis
barplot(data.1, las = 1, col = "black", ylim = c(500, 3000), xpd = F)
par(new = T)
# Plot the new data with a different ylim, but don't plot the axis
barplot(data.2, las = 1, col = "white", ylim = c(0, 30), yaxt = "n")
# Add the axis on the right
axis(4, las = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks Nico. Do you know of a way of aligning the bars properly after changing their width? For instance, I plot the second bar with space=1, as in `barplot(data.2, las = 1, col = "white", ylim = c(0, 30), yaxt = "n", space=1)`, but the bars don't fall right in the middle.

Comment: @stasSajin indeed that's true, not quite sure how to fix that though, sorry

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty easy to make the bars in `ggplot`. Here is some example code. No two y-axes though (although look [here](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) for a way to do that too).

```
library(ggplot2)
data.1 <- sample(1000:2000, 10)
data.2 <- sample(500:1000, 10)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  geom_bar(data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = data.1), width = 0.8, stat = 'identity') +
  geom_bar(data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = data.2), width = 0.4, stat = 'identity', fill = 'white') +
  theme_classic() + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
```

[image]